# 8 bit enum, in C

Tags: c, avr, avr-gcc, winavr, avr-studio4

I have to store instructions, commands that I will be receiving via serial.
The commands will be 8 bits long.

I need to preserve transparency between command name, and its value.
So as to avoid having to translate an 8-bit number received in serial into any type.

I'd like to use Enumerations to deal with them in my code.
Only a enumeration corresponds to a on this platform a 16 bit integer.

The platform is AVR ATmega169V microcontroller, on the [Butterfly demo board](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmel_AVR#Butterfly_demo_board). 
It is a 8bit system with some limited support for 16bit operations.
It is not a fast system and has about 1KB of RAM.
It doesn't have any luxuries like file I/O, or an operating systems.

So any suggestions as to what type I should be using to store 8-bit commands?
There has got to be something better than a massive header of #defines.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`gcc`'s `-fshort-enums` might be useful:

> Allocate to an "enum" type only as
>   many bytes as it needs for the
>   declared range of possible values. 
>   Specifically, the "enum" type will be
>   equivalent to
>   the smallest integer type which has enough room.

In fact, [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/using_tools.html)'s a page with a lot of relevant information. I hope you come across many GCC switches you never knew existed. ;)

Comment: Ha, I realised today that if i compliler via AVR studio 4 IDE, then it's on by default

Comment: I would like to add that on receiving the command, you probably want to make sure the incoming 8bit value is actually a valid value from your enum before you type convert and store it as your enum.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to solve a problem that does not exist.

Your question is tagged C. In C language enum types in value context are fully compatible with integral types and behave just like other integral types. When used in expressions, they are subjected to exactly the same integral promotions as other integral types. Once you take that into account, you should realize that if you want to store values described by enumeration constants in a 8-bit integral type, all you have to do is to choose a suitable generic 8-bit integral type (say `int8_t`) and use it instead of enum type. You'll lose absolutely nothing by storing your enum constant values in an object of type `int8_t` (as opposed to an object explicitly declared with enum type).

The issue you describe would exist in C++, where enum types are separated much farther from other integral types. In C++ using an integral type in place of enum type for the purpose of saving memory is more difficult (although possible). But not in C, where it requires no additional effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see why an enum wouldn't work.  Comparisons to, and assignments from, an enum should all work fine with the default widening.  Just be careful that your 8 bit values are signed correctly (I would think you would want unsigned extension).

You will get 16-bit comparisons this way, I hope that won't be a performance problem (it shouldn't be, especially if your processor is 16-bit as it sounds like it is).

Comment: thing is, my serial input is most deinititly 8bit.
I'm not sure if the ALU works on 16 or 8 bit. Most of thje assembly cannands only work on 8bit bytes, there are less than 5 that works on 2 byte words (ADDW, MOVW is all i can bring to mind).
Only

Comment: @oxinabox - I'm still not sure that that has to do with the size of the enum type. Store the 8bit values in a `uint8_t` variable (or something else that corresponds to a byte). You'll still be able to compare and assign the enum values to them (as long as the enums are less than 256). Just don't use the enum type as the variable type if the exact size is important to the application

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's C compiler allows you to do something like this, but it's an extension (it's standard in C++0x):

```
enum Foo : unsigned char {
    blah = 0,
    blargh = 1
};
```

Since you tagged GCC, I'm not entirely sure if the same thing is possible, but GCC might have an extension in `gnu99` mode or something for it. Give it a whirl.

Comment: Umm, I tagged AVR-GCC.
I'll have to lookup what extentions it supports

Comment: I'm interested in what you find.  This was a gut shot.

Comment: And it seems MS is the only one which supports such syntax.

Comment: Maybe it was added to gcc later, because now it works and **sizeof** of that enum is 1 while regular one is 2.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to stay on enum in any case for the following reasons:

- This solution allows you to map command values directly to what your serial protocol expects.
- If you really use 16-bit architecture there is not so big number of advantages to move to 8 bits type. Think about aspects other then 1 memory byte saved.
- At some compilers I used actual enum size used minimal number of bits (enums that could be fit in byte used only byte, then 16 bit then 32).

First you should not care about real type width. Only if you really need effective way of storage you should use compiler flags such as -fshort-enums on GNU compiler but I don't recommend them unless you really need them.

As last option you can define 'enum' as presentation data for the commands and use conversion to byte with 2 simple operations to store / restore command value to/from memory (and encapsulate this in one place). What about this? These are very simple operations so you can even inline them (but this allows you to really use only 1 byte for storage and from other side to perform operations using most usable enum defined as you like.

Comment: 8 bit architecture. i checked the hardware dos, it's 8bit

Answer (score 0):

Answer which is relevant for **ARC compiler** 
(Quoted from DesignWare MetaWare C/C++ Programmer’s Guide for ARC; section 11.2.9.2)

> Size of Enumerations The size of an enum type depends on the status of toggle *Long_enums*.
>
> ■ If toggle *Long_enums* is off, the enum type maps to the smallest of one, two, or four bytes, such that all values can be represented.
>
> ■ If toggle *Long_enums* is on, an enum maps to
>   four bytes (matching the AT&T Portable C Compiler convention).